# How to get a HTML table that shows after javascript executes with selenium in python

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium, beautifulsoup

So I have this website: https://www.rad.cvm.gov.br/ENETCONSULTA/frmGerenciaPaginaFRE.aspx?NumeroSequencialDocumento=60695&CodigoTipoInstituicao=2

which I'm scrapping to get public info on companies. I've managed to write so far:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
base_url = urls[0] # which is equal to the above url
driver.get(base_url)
driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_cphPopUp_cmbQuadro_cmbQuadro_Input").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_cphPopUp_cmbQuadro_cmbQuadro_c0").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_cphPopUp_cmbQuadro_cmbQuadro_Input").send_keys(u"Balanço Patrimonial Ativo")
```

if you inspect the code on the webpage, it shows the id for the table shown is 'ct100_cphPopUp', however

```
driver.page_source
```

doesn't have this id. What am I getting wrong and how can I read that table?
I guess it appears after a javascript is ran, but I'm not sure of that. If so, how can I know what is the script to do a driver.execute_script() ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, but after a while I found a solution! I was able to do it by using

```
driver.switch_to_frame(0)
```

Pretty simple, isn't it? Happens that the table was not in the HTML (inner, outer, or w/e) but in a separate 'frame'. Although I don't know exactly what this means, it might help others :)